# Google App Engine - Secure Cookies

Tags: google-app-engine, session, forms-authentication, cookies, tornado

I'd been searching for a way to do cookie based authentication/sessions in Google App Engine because I don't like the idea of memcache based sessions, and I also don't like the idea of forcing users to create google accounts just to use a website. I stumbled across someone's [posting](http://blog.jeremi.info/entry/storing-data-in-cookies-in-a-secure-manner) that mentioned some signed cookie functions from the Tornado framework and it looks like what I need. What I have in mind is storing a user's id in a tamper proof cookie, and maybe using a decorator for the request handlers to test the authentication status of the user, and as a side benefit the user id will be available to the request handler for datastore work and such. The concept would be similar to forms authentication in ASP.NET. This code comes from the web.py module of the Tornado framework.

According to the docstrings, it "Signs and timestamps a cookie so it cannot be forged" and
"Returns the given signed cookie if it validates, or None."

I've tried to use it in an App Engine Project, but I don't understand the nuances of trying to get these methods to work in the context of the request handler. Can someone show me the right way to do this without losing the functionality that the FriendFeed developers put into it? The set_secure_cookie, and get_secure_cookie portions are the most important, but it would be nice to be able to use the other methods as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Cookie
import base64
import time
import hashlib
import hmac
import datetime
import re
import calendar
import email.utils
import logging

def _utf8(s):
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        return s.encode("utf-8")
    assert isinstance(s, str)
    return s

def _unicode(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        try:
            return s.decode("utf-8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            raise HTTPError(400, "Non-utf8 argument")
    assert isinstance(s, unicode)
    return s 

def _time_independent_equals(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    result = 0
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        result |= ord(x) ^ ord(y)
    return result == 0

def cookies(self):
    """A dictionary of Cookie.Morsel objects."""
    if not hasattr(self,"_cookies"):
        self._cookies = Cookie.BaseCookie()
        if "Cookie" in self.request.headers:
            try:
                self._cookies.load(self.request.headers["Cookie"])
            except:
                self.clear_all_cookies()
    return self._cookies

def _cookie_signature(self,*parts):
    self.require_setting("cookie_secret","secure cookies")
    hash = hmac.new(self.application.settings["cookie_secret"],
                    digestmod=hashlib.sha1)
    for part in parts:hash.update(part)
    return hash.hexdigest()

def get_cookie(self,name,default=None):
    """Gets the value of the cookie with the given name,else default."""
    if name in self.cookies:
        return self.cookies[name].value
    return default

def set_cookie(self,name,value,domain=None,expires=None,path="/",
               expires_days=None):
    """Sets the given cookie name/value with the given options."""
    name = _utf8(name)
    value = _utf8(value)
    if re.search(r"[\x00-\x20]",name + value):
        # Don't let us accidentally inject bad stuff
        raise ValueError("Invalid cookie %r:%r" % (name,value))
    if not hasattr(self,"_new_cookies"):
        self._new_cookies = []
    new_cookie = Cookie.BaseCookie()
    self._new_cookies.append(new_cookie)
    new_cookie[name] = value
    if domain:
        new_cookie[name]["domain"] = domain
    if expires_days is not None and not expires:
        expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(
            days=expires_days)
    if expires:
        timestamp = calendar.timegm(expires.utctimetuple())
        new_cookie[name]["expires"] = email.utils.formatdate(
            timestamp,localtime=False,usegmt=True)
    if path:
        new_cookie[name]["path"] = path

def clear_cookie(self,name,path="/",domain=None):
    """Deletes the cookie with the given name."""
    expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
    self.set_cookie(name,value="",path=path,expires=expires,
                    domain=domain)

def clear_all_cookies(self):
    """Deletes all the cookies the user sent with this request."""
    for name in self.cookies.iterkeys():
        self.clear_cookie(name)

def set_secure_cookie(self,name,value,expires_days=30,**kwargs):
    """Signs and timestamps a cookie so it cannot be forged"""
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    value = base64.b64encode(value)
    signature = self._cookie_signature(name,value,timestamp)
    value = "|".join([value,timestamp,signature])
    self.set_cookie(name,value,expires_days=expires_days,**kwargs)

def get_secure_cookie(self,name,include_name=True,value=None):
    """Returns the given signed cookie if it validates,or None"""
    if value is None:value = self.get_cookie(name)
    if not value:return None
    parts = value.split("|")
    if len(parts) != 3:return None
    if include_name:
        signature = self._cookie_signature(name,parts[0],parts[1])
    else:
        signature = self._cookie_signature(parts[0],parts[1])
    if not _time_independent_equals(parts[2],signature):
        logging.warning("Invalid cookie signature %r",value)
        return None
    timestamp = int(parts[1])
    if timestamp < time.time() - 31 * 86400:
        logging.warning("Expired cookie %r",value)
        return None
    try:
        return base64.b64decode(parts[0])
    except:
        return None
```

uid=1234|1234567890|d32b9e9c67274fa062e2599fd659cc14

Parts:
   1. uid is the name of the key
   2. 1234 is your value in clear
   3. 1234567890 is the timestamp
   4. d32b9e9c67274fa062e2599fd659cc14 is the signature made from the value and the timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works if anyone is interested:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

import Cookie
import base64
import time
import hashlib
import hmac
import datetime
import re
import calendar
import email.utils
import logging

def _utf8(s):
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        return s.encode("utf-8")
    assert isinstance(s, str)
    return s

def _unicode(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        try:
            return s.decode("utf-8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            raise HTTPError(400, "Non-utf8 argument")
    assert isinstance(s, unicode)
    return s 

def _time_independent_equals(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    result = 0
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        result |= ord(x) ^ ord(y)
    return result == 0


class ExtendedRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """Extends the Google App Engine webapp.RequestHandler."""
    def clear_cookie(self,name,path="/",domain=None):
        """Deletes the cookie with the given name."""
        expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
        self.set_cookie(name,value="",path=path,expires=expires,
                        domain=domain)    

    def clear_all_cookies(self):
        """Deletes all the cookies the user sent with this request."""
        for name in self.cookies.iterkeys():
            self.clear_cookie(name)            

    def cookies(self):
        """A dictionary of Cookie.Morsel objects."""
        if not hasattr(self,"_cookies"):
            self._cookies = Cookie.BaseCookie()
            if "Cookie" in self.request.headers:
                try:
                    self._cookies.load(self.request.headers["Cookie"])
                except:
                    self.clear_all_cookies()
        return self._cookies

    def _cookie_signature(self,*parts):
        """Hashes a string based on a pass-phrase."""
        hash = hmac.new("MySecretPhrase",digestmod=hashlib.sha1)
        for part in parts:hash.update(part)
        return hash.hexdigest() 

    def get_cookie(self,name,default=None):
        """Gets the value of the cookie with the given name,else default."""
        if name in self.request.cookies:
            return self.request.cookies[name]
        return default

    def set_cookie(self,name,value,domain=None,expires=None,path="/",expires_days=None):
        """Sets the given cookie name/value with the given options."""
        name = _utf8(name)
        value = _utf8(value)
        if re.search(r"[\x00-\x20]",name + value): # Don't let us accidentally inject bad stuff
            raise ValueError("Invalid cookie %r:%r" % (name,value))
        new_cookie = Cookie.BaseCookie()
        new_cookie[name] = value
        if domain:
            new_cookie[name]["domain"] = domain
        if expires_days is not None and not expires:
            expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=expires_days)
        if expires:
            timestamp = calendar.timegm(expires.utctimetuple())
            new_cookie[name]["expires"] = email.utils.formatdate(timestamp,localtime=False,usegmt=True)
        if path:
            new_cookie[name]["path"] = path
        for morsel in new_cookie.values():
            self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie',morsel.OutputString(None))

    def set_secure_cookie(self,name,value,expires_days=30,**kwargs):
        """Signs and timestamps a cookie so it cannot be forged"""
        timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
        value = base64.b64encode(value)
        signature = self._cookie_signature(name,value,timestamp)
        value = "|".join([value,timestamp,signature])
        self.set_cookie(name,value,expires_days=expires_days,**kwargs)

    def get_secure_cookie(self,name,include_name=True,value=None):
        """Returns the given signed cookie if it validates,or None"""
        if value is None:value = self.get_cookie(name)
        if not value:return None
        parts = value.split("|")
        if len(parts) != 3:return None
        if include_name:
            signature = self._cookie_signature(name,parts[0],parts[1])
        else:
            signature = self._cookie_signature(parts[0],parts[1])
        if not _time_independent_equals(parts[2],signature):
            logging.warning("Invalid cookie signature %r",value)
            return None
        timestamp = int(parts[1])
        if timestamp < time.time() - 31 * 86400:
            logging.warning("Expired cookie %r",value)
            return None
        try:
            return base64.b64decode(parts[0])
        except:
            return None
```

It can be used like this:

```
class MyHandler(ExtendedRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.set_cookie(name="MyCookie",value="NewValue",expires_days=10)
        self.set_secure_cookie(name="MySecureCookie",value="SecureValue",expires_days=10)

        value1 = self.get_cookie('MyCookie')
        value2 = self.get_secure_cookie('MySecureCookie')
```

Answer (score 12):

`Tornado` was never meant to work with App Engine (it's "its own server" through and through).  Why don't you pick instead some framework that **was** meant for App Engine from the word "go" and is lightweight and dandy, such as [tipfy](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/)?  It gives you authentication using its own user system or any of App Engine's own `users`, OpenIn, OAuth, and Facebook; sessions with secure cookies or GAE datastore; and much more besides, all in a superbly lightweight "non-framework" approach based on WSGI and Werkzeug.  What's not to like?!

Comment: I wasn't intending to use Tornado with App Engine, I just want to set and fetch signed cookies the way they did. I took a look at tipfy/werkzeug secure cookie code and I think what they're doing in Tornado is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still looking, we've extracted just the Tornado cookie implementation that you can use with App Engine at ThriveSmart.  We're using it successfully on App Engine and will continue to keep it updated.

The cookie library itself is at:
http://github.com/thrivesmart/prayls/blob/master/prayls/lilcookies.py

You can see it in action in our example app that's included. If the structure of our repository ever changes, you can look for lilcookes.py within github.com/thrivesmart/prayls

I hope that's helpful to someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to store the user's user ID in the cookie (presumably so you can look their record up in the datastore), you don't need 'secure' or tamper-proof cookies - you just need a namespace that's big enough to make guessing user IDs impractical - eg, GUIDs, or other random data.

One pre-made option for this, which uses the datastore for session storage, is [Beaker](http://beaker.groovie.org/). Alternately, you could handle this yourself with set-cookie/cookie headers, if you really just need to store their user ID.

Comment: Storing the user's id in a cookie is not a problem, but that's not all I'm after. App engine GUIDs aren't impractical to guess, and using some other GUID to authenticate a user seems like a lot more trouble than it's worth. Having the user's id in a signed cookie would solve the problem nicely as long as the hashing algorithm runs reasonably fast. I've looked at Beaker several times before and decided against it because it didn't look like what I wanted.

Comment: I'm sure someone will see this and know exactly how to make the code from Tornado work. It's shown out of context in the question posting, but the code snippets are meant to be a part of the Tornado request handler. I tried extending the webapp request handler, but I couldn't get it to work. The fix is probably something simple, but I need someone with more experience to show me how to do it.

Comment: I'm curious why you're so determined to use Tornado's session module? There are several other good session modules, including Beaker, which provides a signed cookie-only option.

Answer (score 0):

Someone recently extracted the authentication and session code from Tornado and created a new library specifically for GAE.

Perhaps this is more then you need, but since they did it specifically for GAE you shouldn't have to worry about adapting it yourself.

Their library is called gaema.  Here is their announcement in the GAE Python group on 4 Mar 2010:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/d2d6c597d66ecad3/06c6dc49cb8eca0c?lnk=gst&q=tornado#06c6dc49cb8eca0c

Comment: This is pretty cool. The webapp framework should add support for third party authentication mechanisms since it seems to be a popular trend. 

Here's what they say on the gaema page "gaema only authenticates an user, and doesn't provide persistence such as sessions or secure cookies to keep the user logged in.."